# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ejRepository.getWordandMean')

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo, typeorm

I'm trying to retrieve data from a pre-populated database using TypeORM using Expo, imitating this working example (https://dev.to/jgabriel1/expo-sqlite-typeorm-4mn8). It keeps throwing this error;

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ejRepository.getWordandMean')
at src/components/page/dictionarypage.js:32:28 in useCallback$argument_0
at src/components/page/dictionarypage.js:32:28 in useCallback$argument_0
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

**UPDATE**

After some investigation and edits, I've found  out `ejRepository` on dictionarypage.js is undefined, and `context` on connection.tsx is returning an empty object. I'm  wondering why.

It seems like the connection is established already.

Here's my updated code

/page/dictionarypage.js

```
.
.
import { DatabaseConnectionProvider, useDatabaseConnection } from '../../data/connection';
import { setinputWord } from '../../actions/action';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


function DictionaryScreen(props){
    const { inputWord } = props;

    const { ejRepository } = useDatabaseConnection();

           // console.log indicates ejRepository is undefined
    
    const [wordData, setwordData] = useState(""),
          [meanData, setmeanData] = useState("Word and definitions will appear here");
    
 
    const handleinputWord = async () => {
      try {   
            const results = await ejRepository.getWordandMean();
                                         
                                         //this is where the error is thrown

            setwordData(results.word);
            setmeanData(results.mean);

      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
      };


    return(
           <DatabaseConnectionProvider>
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="text-search" color="white" size={30}/>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.input}
                        onChangeText={mapDispatchToProps}
                        onSubmitEditing={handleinputWord}
                        value={inputWord}
                        key={inputWord}
                        placeholder='Look up the word (Type exactly)'
                        keyboardType="default"
                    /> 
                <StatusBar style='light' />
                </View>
                
                <View style={{flex:40, margin:10, alignItems:"center"}}>
                    <Text style={{color:'white',fontSize:30,fontWeight:"bold",margin:10}}>
                        {wordData}
                    </Text>
                    <ScrollView>
                        <Text style={{color:'white',fontSize:18}}>
                        {meanData}
                        </Text>
                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
                <View style={{margin:20, flex:1,alignItems:"center"}}>
                    <Text style={{color:"white",fontSize:11}}>
                        Data retrieved from ****
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
          </DatabaseConnectionProvider>
        );
    }

const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return { 
            inputWord: state.inputWord
        }
    }
    
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
        return {
            onChangeText: inputWord => dispatch(setinputWord({type: 'updateTextInput', inputWord}))
        }
    }
    
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (DictionaryScreen);
```

/data/repositories/repository.ts

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Connection, Repository, Like } from 'typeorm';import { EJmodel } from '../entities/EJmodel';

interface RootState{
    inputWord: string
}

export class EJRepository {
    private ormRepository: Repository<EJmodel>;

    constructor(connection: Connection) {
      this.ormRepository = connection.getRepository(EJmodel);
    }

    public async getWordandMean(): Promise<EJmodel[]> {
        const inputWord = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.inputWord);
    
        const results = await this.ormRepository.find({word: Like(inputWord)}
    );
    
      return results
    }
}
```

/data/entities/EJmodel.ts

```
import {Entity, PrimaryColumn, Column} from "typeorm";

@Entity('ejdict.v1.0')
export class EJmodel {

    @PrimaryColumn({type: 'integer'})
    item_id: number;

    @Column({type: 'text'})
    word: string;

    @Column({type: 'text'})
    mean: string;

    @Column({type: 'integer', select: false})
    level: number;

}
```

/data/connection.tsx

```
import React, {createContext, useCallback, useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { Connection, createConnection } from 'typeorm';
  
import { EJmodel } from './entities/EJmodel';
import { ejdict1621603544180 } from './migration/1621603544180-ejdict';
import { EJRepository } from './repositories/repository';

  
  interface DatabaseConnectionContextData {
    ejRepository: EJRepository;
  }
  
  const DatabaseConnectionContext = createContext<DatabaseConnectionContextData>(
    {} as DatabaseConnectionContextData,
  );
  
  export const DatabaseConnectionProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
    const [connection, setConnection] = useState<Connection | null>(null);
  
    const connect = useCallback(async () => {
      const createdConnection = await createConnection({
        type: 'expo',
        name: "ejdict.v1.0",
        database: 'ejdictcopy.db',
        driver: require('expo-sqlite'),
        entities: [EJmodel],
  
        migrations: [ejdict1621603544180],
        migrationsRun: true,
  
        synchronize: false,
        extra:{
          createFromLocation: '/Users/**/**/assets/db/ejdictcopy.db'
        }
      });
  
      setConnection(createdConnection);
    }, []);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!connection) {
        connect();
      }
    }, [connect, connection]);
  
    if (!connection) {
      return <ActivityIndicator />;
    }
  
    return (
      <DatabaseConnectionContext.Provider
        value={{
          ejRepository: new EJRepository(connection),
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </DatabaseConnectionContext.Provider>
    );
  };
  
  export function useDatabaseConnection() {
    const context = useContext(DatabaseConnectionContext);
  
    return context;
  }
```

Other files and configurations are pretty much the same as the example shown above.

At the beginning, I thought it was because the property `inputWord` was not properly read in the query as a parameter, so I installed react-redux and pass the property as a global variable. However, I feel like that's not the point.

I'd appreciate any help or information about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A possible issue could be that you have declared inputWord as the object and a key within that object, possibly causing a conflict. Try changing the following function in repository.ts:

```
public async getWordandMean(inputWord:{inputWord: String}): Promise<EJmodel> {
const results: EJmodel = await this.ormRepository.query('select * from items where word like ?;',[inputWord],
);
  return results; 
}
```

to:

```
public async getWordandMean(obj:{inputWord: String}): Promise<EJmodel> {
const results: EJmodel = await this.ormRepository.query('select * from items where word like ?;',obj.inputWord,
);
  return results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried the code you suggested but it throws an error "Binding element 'inputWord' implicitly has an 'any' type".

Comment: @mak.skid - updated code below the "to:". Try that, it should work in my opinion.

Comment: Looked promising, but it still doesn't work :(